# Inserting/Selecting/Updating an Object in Redis Cache

Tags: c#, redis

I'm very much new to Redis Cache. The following is my Json string which contains the data.

**Code**

```
[
{
    "ResourceKey": "Members",
    "Language": 1,
    "ClientId": 1,
    "ResourceValue": "Members"
},
{
    "ResourceKey": "Members",
    "Language": 2,
    "ClientId": 1,
    "ResourceValue": "会员"
}
]
```

What I am trying to achieve is that using ResourceKey, LanguageId, ClientId should form a kind of composite key in Redis to retrieve the ResourceValue field.

I have tried to store Json string as it is but it's very difficult to retrieve 1 particular data as I need to deserialize the whole string then get the single value.

**Code**

```
resKeyValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResourceViewModel>>(readTask.Result);
resKeyValue = resKeyValue.Where(x => x.language == iLanguageId && x.clientid == iClientId).ToList();
```

**Code**

```
var db = _redis.GetDatabase();
var addedItems = new List<KeyValuePair<RedisKey, RedisValue>>();
if (!await db.KeyExistsAsync("resourceList"))
{
   addedItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<RedisKey, RedisValue>("resourceList", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resItem)));
   await db.StringSetAsync(addedItems.ToArray());
   return Ok("Resources Added Successfully.");
}
```

I was looking into Hash but NOT able to visualize how to store composite key into Redis. Please help to suggest.

Comment: can you share the code which saves the value to redis?

Comment: @Chetan I updated my code

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interested in `ResourceValue` you can try to concatenate all fields to create a composite key.

For instance

```
set myCompositeKey:Members:1:1 Members
set myCompositeKey:Members:1:2 会员
```

```
get myCompositeKey:Members:1:1
"Members"

get myCompositeKey:Members:1:2
"会员"
```

Prefix `myCompositeKey` can be used to group all keys for that use case or schema. But it is really up to you.

Using this approach we do not use hash data type

Just in case, you can read more about redis keys [here](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-keys)